# Why is the picture not centered in the frame?

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{PSA分析级别和实施程序}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{tikz.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

<sup>The [tikz.pdf](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1gdjK1Gn) is here.</sup>

I obtain this as output:

[image: Image of a diagram in chinese which has different border widths on the left and the right]

As you can see the image is *not* centered, the left margin being significantly bigger than the right one. Why does this happen and how do I properly center it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because even after scaling it, the image's width is bigger than `\textwidth` so it protrudes to the right. With your example code you get a warning about this:

```
Overfull \hbox (11.64403pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--10
```

Instead of scale, control the width using:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tikz.pdf}
```

or a fraction of `\textwidth`:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{tikz.pdf}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{PSA分析级别和实施程序}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tikz.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

With `beamer` there's no need to use placement specifiers (such as `htbp`) since floating is internally suppressed.

If you are not going to use `\caption` for your image, you can get rid of the `figure` environment.